# (posterior mean) = lambda*(prior mean) + (1-lambda)*(max likelihood estimate

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood

Where does this equation come from??  Does anybody know the wikipedia link (or similar) that explains it?

(posterior_mean) = lambda * (prior_mean) + (1-lambda) * (max_likelihood_estimate)

Where:

$$0 \lt lambda < 1$$

and max likelihood estimate is just the mean:

$$\mu_{ML} = \frac{\#success}{\#total}$$

Also, What is Lambda?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say that lambda looks like a weighting percentage between pass and future estimates, if you run this expression recursively upon itself... I'm wondering what you call this expression so I can look it up in a textbook...or maybe lambda is a value you somehow are suppose to choose to minimize errors?  no idea... how would you even know what value to set lambda to get good results?  assuming posterior_mean is more accurate then prior_mean...

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~bapoczos/Classes/ML10715_2015Fall/assignments/hw1_sol.pdf